# What's wrong with the result of these 2x2 and 3x3 matrices equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So i had these two problems  
First is to find the eigenvectors of 2x2 matrix $\pmatrix{3&-2\\2&-1}$
Second is to find the eigenvectors of the 3x3 matrix
$\pmatrix{1&0&-2\\0&1&2\\-1&0&0}$

I started with finding the eigenvalues :

- For 2x2 
  $\pmatrix{3&-2\\2&-1}$ - $\pmatrix{\lambda&0\\0&\lambda}$ = $\pmatrix{3-\lambda&-2\\2&-1-\lambda}$ = 0
  I got
  \begin{align*}
  0 &= (3-\lambda) (-1-\lambda)-(2)(-2) = -3 -3\lambda+1\lambda +\lambda^2 + 4 = \lambda^2 - 2\lambda + 1\\
  &= (-\lambda + 1) (-\lambda + 1)
  \end{align*}
  And there i got $\lambda = -1;  \lambda = -1$.

Then $\pmatrix{3&-2\\2&-1}$ - $\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&-1}$ = $\pmatrix{4&-2\\2&0}$ and i finally got stuck there, how is R2-2R1 transformation able to make it to $\pmatrix{4&-2\\0&0}$ like usual ?? And is everything above even correct ?? 
Because of that i had no choice so i made up everything by doing the following
= $\pmatrix{4&-2\\2&0}$ -> (R/2)-+1 = $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ -+ 1;
= -2x1 + x2 = 0
= x1 = 1/2x2 = eigenvectors = [1/2; 1]
And i am not sure if that is correct

- For 3x3
  \begin{align*}
  0 &= \det \pmatrix{1-\lambda&0&-2\\0&1-\lambda&2\\-1&0&0-\lambda}\\
  &= 1-\lambda[(0-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-(2)(0)] - 0[0-(-2)] + -2[0+1-(-\lambda)]\\
  &= -\lambda+\lambda+\lambda^2-\lambda - -2+2\lambda = 1\lambda - 1\lambda -2+2 \lambda
  \end{align*}
  $$\implies \lambda = 1; \lambda = 1; \lambda = 1 .$$

$\pmatrix{1-1&0&-2\\0&1-1&2\\-1&0&0-1}$
R2 -> R2 - R1 = $\pmatrix{0&0&-2\\0&0&4\\-1&0&5}$

R3 -> R3 - 3R1 = $\pmatrix{0&0&-2\\-1&0&5\\0&0&4}$ = $\pmatrix{0&0&-2\\-1&0&11\\0&0&4}$ = 10x3 = 0, x1+x2 = 0.
Eigenvectors = [0 0 0]

Comment: Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Here is how to write a matrix in MathJax (a variant of LaTex) : `$\pmatrix{a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i}$` giving $\pmatrix{a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i}$ I have begun to change the first two ones.

Comment: for the first matrix, $\lambda=+1$

Comment: For 2x2, you've got $\lambda = -1$, try to double check that with $\lambda^2-2\lambda+1=0$?

Comment: For the eigenvalues, you need $\det(\lambda I -A)=0$ for the eigenvectors, you need $(\lambda I-A)x=0$. If you get incorrect results, it is possible you made a mistake in the computation.

Comment: Yes λ=−1. Most tutorials come up with changing - to + and vice versa. (-λ + 1) since it gets +1 so that λ=−1 based on the available tutorials. (Example (λ+6) then λ = -6).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

For the first matrix, call it $A$, notice that the elements in each row sum the same, $1$. Therefore, $(1,1)$ is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $1$. Now, the trace of the matrix is $2$, which is also the sum of eigenvalues. Therefore, $1$ has a multiplicity of $2$. Now, notice that $$A-I=\begin{pmatrix}2&-2\\2&-2\end{pmatrix}$$
has rank $1$, so there's only one eigenvector associated with $1$, $(1,1)$.

For the second matrix, call it $B$, the second column has all zeroes except in the second entry. Therefore, $(0,1,0)$ is an eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $1$. Now, we have $\text{tr}B=2$ and $\text{det}B=-2$ (the determinant is easy to compute because you can expand the third row). Thus, the remaining eigenvalues $\lambda,\mu$ must satisfy
$$\lambda+\mu=1,\ \lambda \mu=-2,$$
because the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues and the determinant is the product of them. Solve this to get $\lambda=2$ and $\mu=-1$. Now, consider
\begin{align*}&B-2I=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&-2\\0&-1&2\\-1&0&-2\end{pmatrix}\\
&B+I=\begin{pmatrix}2&0&-2\\0&2&2\\-1&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
and get the remaining eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

I shall give my input, building on to your answers. Firstly, for your $2 \times 2$ matrix, you have made a slight mistake. The eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2}=1$.

From the above, we can observe that the algebraic multiplicity is more than the geometric multiplicity. i.e. $\lambda=1$ is of multiplicity $2$. This implies the matrix is not of full-rank, which implies it is not diagonalizable.

We can apply the Jordan normal form. The matrix $A$ can be decomposed to $A=QJQ^{-1}$, where $Q$ consists of the (generalized) eigenvectors, and $J$ consists of your Jordan block.

Let us take the first question - $2 \times 2$ matrix as an example. Let us find the eigenvector associated with $\lambda=1$.
$$A-I=
   \begin{bmatrix} 
   2 & -2  \\
   2 & -2  \\
   \end{bmatrix} 
$$
The eigenvector associated with $\lambda=1$ is:
$$ (A-I)v_1 = 0 $$
$$
v_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
   1  \\
   1  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
Next, we find the other eigenvector $v_2$:
$$(A-I)v_2 = v_1$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & -2  \\
2 & -2  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
x  \\
y  \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 
1  \\
1  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
We can choose:
$$
v_2=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1  \\
\frac{1}{2}  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
The generalized eigenvector is not unique as long as it satisfies the condition above.

Hence,
$$Q =
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1  \\
1 & \frac{1}{2}  \\
\end{bmatrix}
, J =
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1  \\
0 & 1  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
To ensure the answer is correct, you can compute $QJQ^{-1}$ to get back your original matrix $A$.

This method can also be extended to your second question - $3 \times 3$ matrix, where $\lambda = 1$ is of multiplicity $3$. Hence, this can be extended to finding:
$$
\begin{split}
(A-I)v_1 & = 0 \\
(A-I)v_2 & = v_1 \\
(A-I)v_3 & = v_2 \\
\end{split}
$$

You may wiki on generalized eigenvectors or the Jordan normal form if you are not familiar with these concepts. Hope it helps!